# How to show result in json to php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to show value if main= true then if Offer label Money Line or Total Points or Point Spread then show their outcome values otherwise just show blank td

```
$url = 'https://iakshay.website/test/demo.json';  
$data = file_get_contents($url);  
$characters =  json_decode($data, true);  ?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
            <th>Games</th>
            <th>Spread</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Moneyline</th>

        </tr>
<?php foreach ($characters['events'] as $events){
      $str=$events['startDate'];
      $actdate=explode("T",$str);
      <td>".$actdate[0]."</td>";
      <td>".$events['name']."</td>";
    foreach ($events['offers'] as $offers){
        if($offers['main']==true || $offers['main']==1){
            if($offers['label']=="Point Spread"){ ?>
                <td> <?php echo  $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'].')<br/>'. $offers['outcomes'][1]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican']; 
            } else {
                echo '<td> </td>';
            }?></td>

            <?php
            if($offers['label']=="Money line"){ ?>
                <td> <?php echo  $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'].')<br/>'. $offers['outcomes'][1]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican']; 
            } else {
                echo '<td> </td>';
            }?></td>

            <?php
            if($offers['label']=="Total line"){ ?>
                <td> <?php echo  $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'].')<br/>'. $offers['outcomes'][1]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican']; 
            } else {
                echo '<td> </td>';
            }?></td>

        <?php 
        }
echo '<tr>';
    }
}?>
</table>
```

need to show ' no data ' if any offer label main value not true

Result i am getting 
[this is what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7pih.png)
Result what i am expecting
[need to show no data if any offer label main value not true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZsXw.png)

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? What currently happens?

Comment: Btw, you're missing the `<tr>` and  `</tr>` around your `<td>`'s.

Comment: There's also a missing `?>` before you output the HTML.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if i am adding else condition for blank <td> then its looping until all label value Point Spread even main is not true. plus sometimes data going in different <td> like money line data showing in Spread or total.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the expected result (you can mock up the expected HTML output) and what you're currently getting. Should there always be three columns for each row, but depending on the value, the columns could be blank? And do you want to skip the row completely if `$offers['main']==true || $offers['main']==1` isn't true?

Comment: You also seem to be outputting the exact same data regardless what the label is? It's very very unclear what the expected result is here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes but that offer Main value need to be True. Please check updated post

Comment: But that's not the sane table as you've posted? In the screen shot, you have multiple columns with a heading for each column. The posted code has only one heading called `id`.

Comment: yes i have multiple column/row . i am just keeping minimal json for standard post. which json i am using that one is too much huge. if you want i can add one more id in json demo but will be lengthy

Comment: You need to add you _actual code_. If the code you post here looks different from what you have, it's _very_ difficult for us to give you a proper answer (or even to understand the issue fully)

Comment: added one more game id in demo.json . Please let me know if thats enough . @MagnusEriksson

Comment: The JSON wasn't the issue. It's completely impossible for the posted code to generate the result you've posted in the screen shot "this is what I'm getting". For example, you have a different number of columns in your table _and_ different headings. That makes me think that there might be other differences as well. If you want us to help you with the code you have, you need to post _the actual code_.

Comment: Please check i know its huge json but any help will be very big help . @MagnusEriksson

Comment: json is good, first your html is malformated, second you trap php code, example it is `Total Points`  not `Total line`, impossible to help you when your whole code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored a few the code you provide us,
i just use condition `if` and `else` to print column empty or with data and according it's parent `<th>` (e.g Total Points, Money Line, ...).
Everything seems to be good, no duplicates, and all `<td>` go under corresponding `<th>`. Give a try to this code.

```
$url = 'https://iakshay.website/test/demo.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_decode($data, true);
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Date/Time</th>
        <th>Games</th>
        <th>Spread</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Moneyline</th>

    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($characters['events'] as $events) {
        $str = $events['startDate'];
        $actdate = explode("T", $str);
        $row = '';

        foreach ($events['offers'] as $offers) {
            if (isset($offers['main']) && $offers['main']) {
                $row .= '<tr><td>' . $actdate[0] . '</td><td>' . $events["name"] . '</td>';

                if (\strcasecmp($offers['label'], "Point Spread") === 0) {
                    $line = $offers['outcomes'][0]['label'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican = $offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';
                    $line2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['label'] ?? 'No Data';
                    $oddsAmerican2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';

                    $row .= "<td>$line ($oddsAmerican) </br> $line2 ($oddsAmerican2)</td>";

                } else {
                    $row .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
                }

                if (\strcasecmp($offers['label'], "Total Points") === 0) {
                    $line = $offers['outcomes'][0]['label'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican = $offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';
                    $line2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['label'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';

                    $row .= "<td>$line ($oddsAmerican) </br> $line2 ($oddsAmerican2)</td>";

                } else {
                    $row .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
                }

                if (\strcasecmp($offers['label'], "Money line") === 0) {
                    $line = $offers['outcomes'][0]['label'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican = $offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';
                    $line2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['label'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';

                    $row .= "<td>$line ($oddsAmerican) </br> $line2 ($oddsAmerican2)</td>";

                } else {
                    $row .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
                }

                $row .= '</tr>';
                echo $row;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

See the result in picture below.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the code but as you can see its showing NO data on date/ time field. and some fields are repeating also plus some data is not under there <td>

Comment: I edited the answer, can you check with the new code please.

Comment: i am trying from yesterday to show like i need [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZsXw.png) can you please let me little more i am not getting output with your code like this also :(

Answer (score 0):

missing `</tbody>` and `</table>`?

Also, if your second "if" expression returns false you won't have `<td>` but you will have the `</td>`

Comment: That's far from all the issues with the posted code.